# Hardware recommendations for a server used for data storage and exchange with multiple users

Tags: data-storage

I need to assemble a server's hardware for a project with five partners. The server's primary purpose is for data storage and exchange, with approximately ten users storing and retrieving data from it. The anticipated data size is expected to be in the early terabytes, but the software for data storage and retrieval has not yet been decided, and it may involve a SQL database. The budget for the server is 10 000 EUR.

I have found a configuration that i believe may be suitable, but since this is my first time setting up a server at this scale, i would appreciate some advice an opinions.

My proposed configuration includes:

Processor: Intel Xeon Silver 4214 Processor with 12 cores and 24 threads

Memory: 128 GB DDR4 ECC Registered RAM

Storage: 10 x 4 TB SATA Hard Drives in a RAID 6 configuration

Network Interface: 10 GbE NIC

Power Supply: Dual 750W Redundant Power Supplies

Operating System: Ubuntu Sever 20.04 LTS

Chassis: Rackmount server chassis with hot-swappaple drive bays

Backup solution: LTO-8 tape drive with 20 tapes

EDIT: A tower as chassis would probably sufficient as we do not intend to expand the hardware architecture.